# Javascript(EaselJS) - Enemy's have the same functions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods, easeljs

Good day everyone.

I'm trying to develop a dodge game with javascript.

How can I solve the part where all the 3 enemys I create have the same function? I want them to be seperate. As in all three of them should go in the direction which is the outcome of enemyrandom1();

This is the line of code I use to create the enemy.

```
var item:
var enemy;
var enemys = new Array();
function createEnemy(){
enemy = new createjs.Shape();
enemy.graphics.beginFill("black").drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
enemy.x = (Math.random() * 400) +1;
enemy.y = 50
stage.addChild(enemy);
enemys.push(enemy);
console.log(enemys)
}

createEnemy();
createEnemy();
createEnemy();



function enemyforloop(){
for(var i=0;i<enemys.length;i++) {
item = enemys[i];
enemyMove();
}}
```

The enemyforloop is in the Ticker method. Enemymove is a function which is designed to make the enemy move to a direction. After it reaches a certain put it gets put into a random place then it continues.

```
function enemyMove(){
if(enemyrandom == 1)
{
item.y -= enemyspeed;   
    if(item.y < -10)
    {
        enemyrandom1();
    }
}

function enemyrandom1(){

enemyrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
enemyspeed = Math.random() *2 + 1;

if(enemyrandom == 1){
    item.y = 300;
    item.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);     
}
}
```

I skipped enemyrandom and enemymove 2,3,4 so it wouldnt take more space in the question.
I hope I was clear enough with my question.

This is what it looks like right now http://jsfiddle.net/HqYeD/411/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the global `enemyspeed` and `enemyrandom` and scope those variables to each enemy.

```
function createEnemy() {
    enemy = new createjs.Shape();
    enemy.graphics.beginFill("black").drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    enemy.x = (Math.random() * 400) +1;
    enemy.y = 5;

    // scope direction and speed to each enemy
    enemy.enemyspeed = Math.random() *2 + 1;
    enemy.enemyrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

    stage.addChild(enemy);
    enemys.push(enemy);
    console.log(enemys)
}
```

change your rest of  code based on this...

```
function enemyMove() {
    if(item.enemyrandom == 1) {  // use scoped direction
        item.y -= item.enemyspeed;   // use scoped speed
        if(item.y < -10)
        {
            enemyrandom1();
        }
    }
  // ....
 }
```

Similarly...

```
function enemyrandom1() {

    item.enemyrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    item.enemyspeed = Math.random() *2 + 1;

    if(item.enemyrandom == 1){
        item.y = 300;
        item.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);     
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I tried and It worked. Thank you. I'm still trying to understand what exactly I did wrong. So I wont repeat the same mistake. Never would've thought of this solution though. But it does make alot of sense. Thank you agian.

Answer (score 0):

You have scoped the "item" in the global scope (similar to the initial example you posted on the CreateJS community where you scope the "enemy" in the global scope as well), so you have the same problem.

Instead, the `item` should be declared *inside* the function, and passed into the "enemyMove" method:

```
function enemyforloop(){
    for(var i=0;i<enemys.length;i++) {
        var item = enemys[i]; // NOTE THE VAR USED HERE!
        enemyMove(item); // ITEM IS PASSED IN HERE!
    }
}
function enemyMove(item){
    // This code should not need to change.
}
```

Make sure you remove the "var item" at the top of your code. You should only declare things like this that don't need to change during their lifespan. Your `enemy` and `item` objects are transient, and change often.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After reading your explanation. I kind of know where I went wrong. However your solution hasn't worked for me. I could've been doing it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to share your solution!